# How to log value in karma

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hi I'm trying to console log / console error from karma tests - but there is no any logs in terminal!

```
 it('should not delete card on deleteCard method if user cancels', async(() => {
    const eventMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('event', ['preventDefault', 'stopPropagation']);
    const testCard = testCards[1];
    cardsServiceSpy.deleteCard.calls.reset();
    actionSheetDismissService.canDismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(false));
    console.log(testCard);
    component.deleteCard(eventMock, testCard).then((dataOnDelete) => {
      console.log(dataOnDelete);
      expect(dataOnDelete).toBe(testCard.id);
      expect(cardsServiceSpy.deleteCard).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.cards.length).toBe(3);
    });
  }));
```

What I'm missing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (config) {
 config.set({
 basePath: '',
 frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
 plugins: [
   require('karma-jasmine'),
   require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
   require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
   require('karma-coverage'),
   require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
 ],
 client: {
   jasmine: {
    // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
    // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
    // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
    // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
   },
   clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
   captureConsole: true,    
 },
  // ...........
  // ...........
});
};
```

Set captureConsole flag to true, in karma.conf.js file.